# Homology, Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am having a hard time computing the following homology.  Any help will be appreciated.

Compute $H_n(S^2 \times S^2)$

Comment: In particular is there a way to do this without the Kunneth formula?

Comment: You could also use Mayer-Vietoris. Or the long exact sequence associated to the pair $(S^2 \times S^2, S^2 \vee S^2)$.

Answer (score 10):

Just give $S^2 \times S^2$ the product CW structure coming from the usual CW structure on $S^2$ and use cellular homology.

In more detail: $S^2$ has a CW structure with one $0$-cell $e^0$ and one $2$-cell $e^2$. Then the product CW structure on $S^2 \times S^2$ induced by the given CW structure on $S^2$ has one $0$-cell $e^0 \times e^0$, two $2$-cells $e^2 \times e^0$ and $e^0 \times e^2$, and one $4$-cell $e^2 \times e^2$. Hence the cellular chain complex $(C_i(S^2 \times S^2), \partial)$ (assuming coefficients in $\Bbb Z$) is
$$\cdots \to 0 \to \Bbb Z \to 0 \to \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \to 0 \to \Bbb Z.$$
Since there are only nonzero cellular chain groups in even degrees, all boundary maps are zero and the cellular homology groups are the same as the cellular chain groups:
$$H_i(S^2 \times S^2; \Bbb Z) \cong \begin{cases} \Bbb Z, & i = 0, 4, \\ \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z, & i = 2, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$